# Java UnfinishedVerificationException when using isNull

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following mock:

```java
when(manager.list(eq(userId), eq(0), isNull())).thenReturn(completedFuture(user));

// call some method

verify(configurationsManager).list(any(), any(), isNull());
```

When I run this, I get a

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
```

And it's referencing `verify(configurationsManager).list(any(), any(), isNull());` line. What am I doing wrong?

The `list` method is:

```
public CompletionStage<User> list(UserId, int, Token)
```

where `UserId` and `Token` are custom classes.

Comment: I think you mean `thenReturn`, not `doReturn`.

Comment: @Kousha What are the types of the parameters of the `list()` method?

Comment: @entpnerd updated.

Comment: @khelwood sorry that was a typo

Comment: You might also want to add what the actual parameters are when the method is called while you are executing your test. Also did you verify that the `list` method on your mock is actually invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem might the use of the `any()` method when matching the second `int` type variable of your `list()` method. In my experience, the `any()` method tends not to work well with primitive types. As such, I would use `anyInteger()` instead. Thus, your new line would be:

```
verify(configurationsManager).list(any(), anyInteger(), isNull());
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried casting the `isNull()` matcher to the class the `list` method takes in? As in, if the second parameter is of type `int`, you can try:

`verify(configurationsManager).list(any(), any(), (int) isNull());`